# Folland Exercise 5.36 item c.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, separable-spaces

Exercise 5.36 in Folland's *Real Analysis* reads as follows:

> Let $X$ be a separable Banach space and let $\mu$ be the counting measure on $\mathbb N$. Suppose that $\{x_n\}$ is a countbale dense subset of the unit ball of $X$ and define $T:L^1(\mu) \to X$ as
> $$
> Tf = \sum_1^\infty f(n) x_n.
> $$
> a. Show that $T$ is bounded.
> b. Show that $T$ is surjective.
> c. Show that $X$ is isomorphic to a quotient space of $L^1(\mu)$.

My question regards item c. Folland gives a hint of looking at exercise 5.35, which reads as

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces, $T \in L(X, Y)$, $N(T) = \{x : Tx = 0\}$ and $M =$ range$(T)$. Show that $X/N(T)$ is isomorphic to $M$ iff $M$ is closed.

Looking at exercise 35, the first thing that comes to mind in to take $N(T)$ for $T$ defined in exercise 36. However, this seems too simple. What exactly does he want, and how do we proceed? Do we even know if $N(T)$ is not trivial?

Thanks in advance and kind regards.

Comment: It is that simple, the intention is to take $N(T)$. Whether that's trivial or not, by continuity of $T$ it's closed. And we have an induced continuous linear $\tilde{T}\colon L^1(\mu)/N(T) \to X$. Now look at b. and a famous theorem.

Comment: By isomorphism, $N(T)$ is trivial if and only if $X$ is a single point $\{0\}$? @DanielFischer

Comment: No, if $X = \{0\}$, then $N(T) = L^1(\mu)$. Actually, we never have $N(T) = \{0\}$, but that fact is not needed.

Comment: That was dumb, I apologize.

Comment: No need to apologise. It's an everyday mistake.

Comment: Please, it is still unclear to me, what famous theorem are you referring to? How to show that $N(T)$ is never trivial?

Comment: @DaniloGregorin: It seems that the key is to show (b). It is easy to see that $T(L_1(\mu))$ is dense in $X$, The tricky part is to show that actually $T(L_1)=X$. That may be what Daniel Fischer's "famous theorem"  is alluding to.

Comment: The famous theorem is the open mapping theorem, but that's used in exercise 35. To know it's applicable, one needs part b. Let me reiterate, we do _not_ need the fact that $N(T) \neq \{0\}$. To see that fact, suppose $x_1 \neq 0$ (otherwise it's just an indexing change). Clearly $T(1,0,\dotsc) = x_1$. Now we need to find another sequence in $L^1(\mu)$ that is mapped to $x_1$. There is an $n_2 > 1$ with $0 < \lVert x_1 - x_{n_2}\rVert < 2^{-2}$ by denseness. Let $y_2 = 2^1\cdot (x_1 - x_{n_2})$. There is an $n_3 > n_2$ with $0<\lVert y_2- x_{n_3}\rVert < 2^{-3}$. Let $y_3 = 2^2(y_2 - x_{n_3})$.

Comment: You can continue this construction, at the end you find that $T$ maps $e_{n_2} + 2^{-1}e_{n_3} + 2^{-2}e_{n_4} + \ldots$ to $x_1$ too.

Comment: Thank you both very much @DanielFischer and OliverDiaz, it is very clear now.

Comment: @DaniloGregorin: I added a solution to part (b). The rest, once you believed, or solve problem 5-35, follows trough with $T(L_1(\mu))=X$ in lieu of $M$.

Answer (score 1):

Part(c) follows follows from (a) and (b) by the hint offered in the OP with $T(L_1(\mu))=X$ in lieu of $M$.

Here is a short proof that this is the case:

Fist by (a) $T$ is continuous and so $N_T=\{f\in L_1(\mu): Tf=0\}$ is a close subset of $L_1(\mu)$. Being that $L_1(\mu)$ is Banach space, we have that $L_1(\mu)/N_T$, with the [quotient topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space#General_theory),  is a Banach space under the norm $$\|f^*\|:=\inf_{g\in N_T}\|f-g\|_{L_1(\mu)}$$
Let $\pi:L_1(\mu)\rightarrow L_1(\mu)/N_T$  be the quotient map.

By (b) $T$ is surjective, by a well known [result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)#Properties), there exists a unique continuous map
$$\phi:L_1(\mu)/N_T\rightarrow Y$$
such that $\phi\circ \pi =T$, namely
$$\phi(f+N_T)=Tf$$
It is easy to check that $\phi$ is linear, bounded and one to one and onto. The continuity of $\phi^{-1}$ follows from the open map theorem (Here we use the fact that $Y$ is a Banach space).

---

Here we furnish short proofs that (a) and (b) hold.

---

(a) $\|Tf\|_X\leq \sum_n|f(n)|\|x_n\|_X\leq \sum_n |f(n)|=\|f\|_1$

(b) is a little tricky. Here is one possible solution.

For each $m\in\mathbb{N}$, define $e_m(n)=\mathbb{1}_{\{m\}}(n)$. Clearly $e_m\in L_1(\mu)$, $\|e_m\|_{L_1(\mu)}=1$,  and $Te_n=x_n$.

It is enough to show that $B_X(0;1)\subset T(L_1(\mu))$. Let $y_1=y\in B(0;1)$. There exists $x_{n_1}$ such that
$$
\big\|\tfrac{y_1}{\|y_1\|_X} -x_{n_1}\big\|<\frac12
$$
and so,
$$
\big\|y_1-\|y_1|_Xx_{n_1}\big\|_X\leq\frac12\|y_1\|_X\leq\frac12
$$
Set $y_2=y_1-\|y\|_Xx_{n_1}$. Then, $\|y_2\|_X\leq\frac12$, and there is $x_{n_2}$ such that
$$
\big\|\tfrac{y_2}{\|y_2\|_X} -x_{n_2}\big\|<\frac{1}{2^2},
$$
which in turn implies that
$$\big\|y_1-\|y_1\|_Xx_{n_1}-\|y_2\|_Xx_{n_2}\big\|_X=\big\|y_2-\|y_2\|_Xx_{n_2}\big\|_X\leq\frac{1}{2^2}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2^{2+1}}
$$
proceeding by induction, we obtain sequences $\{y_k:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $\{x_{n_k}:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ such that
$$
y_k=y_{k-1}-\|y_{k-1}\|_Xx_{n_{k-1}}=y_1-\Big(\|y_{n_{k-1}}\|_Xx_{n_{k-1}} +\ldots+ \|y_1\|_Xx_{n_1}\big),
$$
$$
\|y_k\|_X\leq \frac{1}{2^{(k-1)+\ldots+1}},
$$
and
$$
\big\|\tfrac{y_{n_k}}{\|y_{n_k}\|_X} -x_{n_k}\big\|<\frac{1}{2^k},
$$
which in turn implies that
$$
\big\|y_{n_{k+1}}\big\|_X=\big\|y_k-\|y_{n_k}\|x_{n_k}\big\|_X\leq \frac{1}{2^k}\|y_{n_k}\|_X\leq \frac{1}{2^{k+(k-1)+\ldots+1}}
$$
It follows that $f=\sum^\infty_{k=1}\|y_k\|_Xe_{n_k}\in L_1(\mu)$ since
$$
\sum^\infty_{k=1}\big\|\|y_k\|_Xe_{n_k}\big\|_{L_1(\mu)}=\sum^\infty_{k=1}\|y_k\|_X<\sum^\infty_{k=1}2^{-k}=1
$$
Furthermore,
$$
Tf=\sum^\infty_{k=1}\|y_k\|_Xx_{n_k}=x
$$
Therefore $\overline{B}_X(0;1)\subset T\big(B_{L_1(\mu)}(0;1)\big)$.